# AJAX: How to replace content of a DIV with a link in same DIV?

Tags: php, ajax, json, html, hyperlink

**I have index.php like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

<a href='one.php' class='ajax'>One</a>

<div id="workspace">workspace</div>
```

**one.php**

```
<?php
$arr = array ( "workspace" => "<a href='two.php' class='ajax'>two</a>" );
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**two.php**

```
<?php 
$arr = array( 'workspace' => "Hello World" );
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.ajax').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // load the href attribute of the link that was clicked
        jQuery.getJSON(this.href, function(snippets) {
            for(var id in snippets) {
                // updated to deal with any type of HTML
                jQuery('#' + id).html(snippets[id]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When index.php is loaded, there is a link(One) and a DIV(workspace). When I click 'One' link then content of one.php is called and link 'Two' appeared in 'workspace' DIV successfully.

But now when I click link 'Two' then 'Hello World' does not appear in 'workspace' DIV and opened separately without AJAX call.

**How to force this code to replace content of workspace DIV with 'Hello World' using link 'TWO' with above flow?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method instead of `click`:

```
jQuery('.ajax').live('click', function(event) {
  // your code
});
```

The `live` is used when the content you have assigned events to is either present or is added/loaded later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the init method that makes the ".ajax" links so magical is only being called once, when the document loads. When you replace the html the magic is lost.

Try this:

```
function assignLinks() {

    jQuery('.ajax').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // load the href attribute of the link that was clicked
            jQuery.getJSON(this.href, function(snippets) {
                for(var id in snippets) {

                    // updated to deal with any type of HTML
                    jQuery('#' + id).html(snippets[id]).click( function() {
                        assignLinks();
                    });
                }
            });
        });

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    assignLinks();        
});
```

Or, just use live (as stated below).

Comment: Ah, you're right. The problem is that the init method that looks at ".ajax" is only being called once, when the document loads (so the subsequent changes aren't affected). Will update in a sec...