# need help to learn ajax with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

any can suggest me the link to learn ajax with jquery.. i am unable to select one site in this ocean.. please suggest the link which can cover from basic.. not only link if there is any book i feel great

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the only function you'll need (until you do really crazy stuff) is $.ajax()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It will send data to a script and get the result back.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'path/to/script.php',
        type:'post'
        data:'variable=somevalue&this=that'
        success:function(data){
            // this is the function that is called if it succeeded. the data argument is the output from script.php (if you echo'd out stuff, for example.)
        }
    });
```

Best of luck, and merry Christmas.

Comment: Thank you wish u the same(Merry christmas)

Comment: You are welcome :) I usually echo out a single result from my PHP script and test against that. JS has some nice string searching tools that you can also use.

Comment: . if we not pass this data and we put only url as static html and type did i get any error?

Comment: Your English makes no sense. Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 3):

[Easy Ajax with jQuery](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery)

**I also learned AJAX/jQuery step by step from this platform by postings different scenarios question. Here are my some questions that will be helpful for you also**

- [How to load more than one DIVs using AJAX-JSON combination in zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326614/how-to-load-more-than-one-divs-using-ajax-json-combination-in-zend)
- [AJAX: How to replace content of a DIV with a link in same DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426276/ajax-how-to-replace-content-of-a-div-with-a-link-in-same-div)
- [How to call AJAX request on dropdown change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429176/how-to-call-ajax-request-on-dropdown-change-event)
- [How to pass values of form input fields to a script using AJAX/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429858/how-to-pass-values-of-form-input-fields-to-a-script-using-ajax-jquery)
- [How to submit a form with AJAX/JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438123/how-to-submit-a-form-with-ajax-json)
- [How to code one jquery function for all AJAX links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272384/how-to-code-one-jquery-function-for-all-ajax-links)

Some of these are zend framework specific but jQuery/AJAX part will be same for all cases.